# Django Model From API Call

Tags: json, django

I would like to take advantage of an API that returns a JSON object. This object I would like to convert into a Django model so that I can interact with it just like a model, but instead of it storing it in the database, the API would act as the database. Is this possible? Does this require a custom "database" backend to accomplish it? The reason why I would like to map the data into a pseudo model is so that I can work with the data in class based views easier.

Comment: It really depends on the type of data that the JSON stores... We would need more info about the thing you want to achieve.

Comment: For example I would like to take the data returned from Google's Calendar API and use it as if it was a model in the database. Essentially using the Google Calendar as my database backend.
https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/calendar_v3.html

Comment: Ok then you would need to parse the JSON and add the appropriate field types for all the data provided in the JSON. There is really no standard way of doing that so need to try it on your own.